# git difftool: how to compare zip files

Tags: git, git-diff, beyondcompare3

I am trying to compare a binary file using "git difftool". This file is also staged, but it seems that this isn't important. So I am using something like below:

```
git difftool --staged /path/to/file
```

and my .gitconfig is configured like so:

```
[difftool "bc3"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.com
    cmd = BComp.com \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -lefttitle="Remote" -righttitle="$BASE" -lro
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

So when I run `git difftool` it opens Beyond Compare as expected, however, I get an error that the base binary file doesn't exist. The modified local copy is correctly loaded into the tool.

I have noticed this with *.bcpkg (Beyond Compare settings file, a zip file basically), and also regular *.zip files. But seems to work fine for *.exe files. What I have noticed is that `git difftool` shouldn't return unless Beyond Compare is closed, because if it returns the temp file created by it gets deleted. But in case of a zip file it always returns immediately.

By the way diff for all other file types works fine for me. I am on Windows 7 (64-bit) and as you can see have configured Beyond Compare 3.

Comment: Git does not handle diffs on binary files well, from what I understand.  This is the reason why many do not use Git for versioning binary files.  I don't see anything unexpected in your question.

Comment: That's dissapointing... can I extract the "base" file, and staged files outside of the repo to manually compare them using my tool?

Comment: If the "base" files are plain text, source code, etc. and not binary, then yes that should work.

Comment: So to be clear you are saying, that if the file were a text file, I could extract the base file (file matching the last commit state), and/or the file in the staging area, somewhere outside the repo. And compare them through whatever means. But the same mechanism doesn't work for binary files?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen true that Git doesn't handle binary diffs well, but OP is configuring an external tool to handle those diffs, which is fine.

Comment: @1615903 Are you certain that the external diff tool is able to do any better than Git?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, beyond compare can handle many binary files well, including zip files.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think it is obvious that the external tool has a better chance at this since Git clearly is unable to handle binary files well, as you just suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Beyond Compare 4. Beyond Compare 4 supports diffing zip files from git.

Beyond Compare 3 doesn't support diffing zip files from git. It will fail with the error message: **Folder Not Available: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\42Ycl9_filename.zip**

If you want to evaluate Beyond Compare 4 to test zip file diffs, run the installer and select **Create portable install** and install to a folder on your desktop. This doesn't require admin rights. Then run **git config --global difftool.bc3.path "c:/users/username/desktop/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe"** to make git use the portable install. After you're done testing, just delete the folder on your desktop to remove the version 4 portable install.

To upgrade your license after evaluating a trial of version 4, fill in the [upgrade form](http://www.scootersoftware.com/shop.php?zz=shop_upgrade_cart) on the Scooter Software website.

Comment: This is not correct... I can diff zip files just fine with TortoiseSVN, where I have hooked up Beyond Compare in the same way. Moreover, if you look closely I am using BComp.com and not BComp.exe, which does not return until the comparison tab is closed. This is true for even those cases where Beyond Compare has an existing instance already running.

Comment: Just realized you are an employee at Scooter Software, so most probably I am the one wrong here :p

Comment: I talked to a colleague about this issue, the behavior might have changed from BC3 to BC4. I'll do some investigation today and update my post.

Comment: I edited my answer. "git difftool" for zip files is supported in Beyond Compare 4. Beyond Compare 3 doesn't support diffing zip files from git.

Comment: Well that was it, trying with BC4 worked. Thanks a lot. Any workarounds for BC3?

Comment: There isn't a good workaround for BC3. If you're using version 3, you'll have to check out the two revisions of the zip file to temp folders, then launch the comparison outside of git.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, [this article](https://tante.cc/2010/06/23/managing-zip-based-file-formats-in-git/) shows how you can configure git to unzip files with chosen extensions before your standard diff is run on it. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I am wondering if this technique is of practical use. I assume it would be good enough for simple cases, but a zip file containing many files would be extremely hard to diff like this. A much more intuitive way to diff them is like Beyond Compare does, in folder comparison view.

Comment: @WaqasIlyas, oh, right, absolutely. This particular technique would work for file formats that are basically one (somewhat verbose) file that's then zipped (for compression), like for example the "new" Office formats .docx, .xlsx, etc.